# Format specific ranges of a Pivot Table (Aspose.Cells Java library)

Tags: pivot-table, aspose

I would like to apply format on a specific range of cells of a pivot table containing values for a given data field. More specifically I want to **create a border around the range of values**.
This is possible in VBA with *PivotTable.PivotSelect* method which has a data field name as parameter and then we can apply format on this selection.

I have not found any solution yet in Aspose documentation for this.
I am aware of PivotTable.getDataBodyRange() Aspose method which returns the area of the data field values, but the thing is that I want to select only a specific data field.

Answer (score 0):

You can format specific data area values in the Pivot Table via Aspose.Cells for Java. See the following example for your complete reference. I demonstrated to apply formatting via both ways (i.e., directly apply formatting and via pivot format conditions).

e.g.

**Sample code:**

```java
        //Instantiating a Workbook object
        Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

        //Obtaining the reference of the newly added worksheet
        int sheetIndex = workbook.getWorksheets().add();
        Worksheet sheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(sheetIndex);
        Cells cells = sheet.getCells();

        //Setting the value to the cells
        Cell cell = cells.get("A1");
        cell.setValue("Sport");
        cell = cells.get("B1");
        cell.setValue("Quarter");
        cell = cells.get("C1");
        cell.setValue("Sales");

        cell = cells.get("A2");
        cell.setValue("Golf");
        cell = cells.get("A3");
        cell.setValue("Golf");
        cell = cells.get("A4");
        cell.setValue("Tennis");
        cell = cells.get("A5");
        cell.setValue("Tennis");
        cell = cells.get("A6");
        cell.setValue("Tennis");
        cell = cells.get("A7");
        cell.setValue("Tennis");
        cell = cells.get("A8");
        cell.setValue("Golf");

        cell = cells.get("B2");
        cell.setValue("Qtr3");
        cell = cells.get("B3");
        cell.setValue("Qtr4");
        cell = cells.get("B4");
        cell.setValue("Qtr3");
        cell = cells.get("B5");
        cell.setValue("Qtr4");
        cell = cells.get("B6");
        cell.setValue("Qtr3");
        cell = cells.get("B7");
        cell.setValue("Qtr4");
        cell = cells.get("B8");
        cell.setValue("Qtr3");

        cell = cells.get("C2");
        cell.setValue(1500);
        cell = cells.get("C3");
        cell.setValue(2000);
        cell = cells.get("C4");
        cell.setValue(600);
        cell = cells.get("C5");
        cell.setValue(1500);
        cell = cells.get("C6");
        cell.setValue(4070);
        cell = cells.get("C7");
        cell.setValue(5000);
        cell = cells.get("C8");
        cell.setValue(6430);

        PivotTableCollection pivotTables = sheet.getPivotTables();

        //Adding a PivotTable to the worksheet
        int index = pivotTables.add("=A1:C8", "E3", "PivotTable2");

        //Accessing the instance of the newly added PivotTable
        PivotTable pivotTable = pivotTables.get(index);

        //Unshowing grand totals for rows.
        pivotTable.setRowGrand(false);

        //Dragging the first field to the row area.
        pivotTable.addFieldToArea(PivotFieldType.ROW, 0);

        //Dragging the second field to the column area.
        pivotTable.addFieldToArea(PivotFieldType.COLUMN, 1);

        //Dragging the third field to the data area.
        pivotTable.addFieldToArea(PivotFieldType.DATA, 2);

        pivotTable.refreshData();
        pivotTable.calculateData();

        /*
        //Apply formatting to specific data area values via Pivot format condition.
        PivotFormatConditionCollection pfcc = pivotTable.getPivotFormatConditions();
        int pIndex = pfcc.add();
        PivotFormatCondition pfc = pfcc.get(pIndex);
        FormatConditionCollection fcc = pfc.getFormatConditions();
        CellArea dataBodyRange = pivotTable.getDataBodyRange();
        fcc.addArea(dataBodyRange);
        int idx = fcc.addCondition(FormatConditionType.CELL_VALUE);
        FormatCondition fc = fcc.get(idx);
        fc.setFormula1("6000");
        fc.setOperator(OperatorType.GREATER_OR_EQUAL);
        //fc.getStyle().setBackgroundColor(com.aspose.cells.Color.getRed());
        fc.getStyle().setBorder(BorderType.LEFT_BORDER, CellBorderType.THICK, com.aspose.cells.Color.getRed());
        fc.getStyle().setBorder(BorderType.TOP_BORDER, CellBorderType.THICK, com.aspose.cells.Color.getRed());
        fc.getStyle().setBorder(BorderType.RIGHT_BORDER, CellBorderType.THICK, com.aspose.cells.Color.getRed());
        fc.getStyle().setBorder(BorderType.BOTTOM_BORDER, CellBorderType.THICK, com.aspose.cells.Color.getRed());
        */
        ///*
        //Apply formatting directly to specific data fields 
        CellArea dataArea = pivotTable.getDataBodyRange();
        for(int dataRowNum = dataArea.StartRow; dataRowNum <= dataArea.EndRow;dataRowNum++){
            for(int dataColNum = dataArea.StartColumn;dataColNum <= dataArea.EndColumn;dataColNum++){
                cell = cells.get(dataRowNum,dataColNum);
                int value = cell.getIntValue();
                System.out.println(value);
                if (value > 6000) {
                Style style = cell.getStyle();
                com.aspose.cells.Font font = style.getFont();
                font.setColor(com.aspose.cells.Color.getBlue());
                style.setBorder(BorderType.LEFT_BORDER, CellBorderType.THICK, com.aspose.cells.Color.getRed());
                style.setBorder(BorderType.TOP_BORDER, CellBorderType.THICK, com.aspose.cells.Color.getRed());
                style.setBorder(BorderType.RIGHT_BORDER, CellBorderType.THICK, com.aspose.cells.Color.getRed());
                style.setBorder(BorderType.BOTTOM_BORDER, CellBorderType.THICK, com.aspose.cells.Color.getRed());
                pivotTable.format(dataRowNum, dataColNum, style);

                }
            }
        }
        workbook.save("f:\\files\\out1.xlsx");
```

Should you have any confusion or further queries, you may also post your queries in respective [forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells/9).

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't fix my problem. What you proposed is to apply format cell by cell but this implies to know in advance the precise area. Here I don't know the area, I want Aspose to find it automatically by referring the name of the data field.

Comment: I have updated the example code now. Hope this helps you.